# Scrolling down custom scroller with Selenium for Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, screen-scraping

I need to access some data that is shown after scrolling a custom scroll bar inside a website. (Not the general scrolling function)

Selenium seems to be unable to locate it without performing such action first.

I have checked similar replies but all of them teach you how to scroll down the page and not a bar inside the UI, or they provide solutions for other languages like Python.

Is it possible to do this with the selenium-webdriver for Ruby?

---

This is the website: http://www.lamiecaline.com/fr/magasins?address=&city=70

The elements I want to access are on the left side, Selenium is only able to access the first 4 elements by default.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do but I'm 99% sure there's an easier way

Comment: You are right. In this case, I found that the urls of all elements are accessible without scrolling so I was able to get them and visit them on a loop to get the data for each individual item. In the case they hadn't been urls I would have had to find a way to make the data below the scroll limit accessible though...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try an execute_script with parameters.
Like so:

```
execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[1];", myElement, pixels)
```

You may have to import the PageObject gem.
myElement would be your mCSB_container div.